# What is the proper way to pass a reactive pinia state as axios params?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, pinia

I am trying to use two pinia stores for my axios params but when I send the axios request, the state is sent as a whole proxy object.

**stores/product-filter.js**

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useProductFilterStore = defineStore("productFilter", {
  state: () => ({
    id: undefined,
    title: undefined,
    ...
  }),
});
```

**stores/product-pagination.js**

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useProductPaginationStore = defineStore("productPagination", {
  state: () => ({
    pagination: {
      page: 1,
      rowsPerPage: 15,
      rowsNumber: false,
    },
  }),
});
```

**stores/product.js**

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

import { useProductFilterStore } from "./product-filter";
import { useProductPaginationStore } from "./product-pagination";

const paginationStore = useProductPaginationStore();
const filterStore = useProductFilterStore();

export const useProductStore = defineStore("product", {
  state: () => ({
    products: [],
  }),

  actions: {
    fetchProducts() {
      return axios.get(process.env.API_URL + "product", {
        params: {
          limit: paginationStore.pagination.rowsPerPage,
          page: paginationStore.pagination.page,
          filter: filterStore,
        },
      });
    },
  },
});
```

So when I `fetchProducts` I get the whole object like

```
limit: 15
page: 1
filter[$id]: productFilter
filter[_isOptionsAPI]: true
filter[router][currentRoute][__v_isShallow]: true
filter[router][currentRoute][dep][w]: 0
filter[router][currentRoute][dep][n]: 0
filter[router][currentRoute][__v_isRef]: true
filter[router][currentRoute][_rawValue][fullPath]: /product
filter[router][currentRoute][_rawValue][hash]: 
filter[router][currentRoute][_rawValue][name]: api.product.index
filter[router][currentRoute][_rawValue][path]: /product
filter[router][currentRoute][_rawValue][matched][][path]: /
filter[router][currentRoute][_rawValue][matched][][name]: api.default
```

Trying the following doesn't work either:

```js
...
const { filter } = storeToRefs(filterStore);
...

params: {
  limit: paginationStore.pagination.rowsPerPage,
  page: paginationStore.pagination.page,
  filter: filterStore,
},
```

What is the best way to do this (reactively) ?

Comment: try `filterStore.$state`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `stores/product.js`, you are passing the entire store to Axios.
It seems you want to pass just the state of the store, so try this:

```js
fetchProducts() {
  return axios.get(process.env.API_URL + "product", {
    params: {
      limit: paginationStore.pagination.rowsPerPage,
      page: paginationStore.pagination.page,
      filter: filterStore.$state, // This
    },
  });
},
```

P.S. This was independently pointed out by [Michal Levý](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381282/michal-lev%c3%bd) in a comment on your question.